# Why do some pages require access token and others don't in Graph API?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

You can do this (Shrek movie page): https://graph.facebook.com/355374000182 without an access token (go ahead and click and see for yourself).

But you can't do it for The Hangover movie page: https://graph.facebook.com/74089565764. It returns false.

Why the discrepancy between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be age and/or country restrictions on the Hangover's page and none on the Shrek page. Pages with any kind of restriction can only be viewed by an authenticated user. This includes API calls.

More interesting is if you try to visit the Hangover page by visiting https://www.facebook.com/74089565764. If I am logged into FB, I get the page. If not, I get a "Not Found" page. Even visiting https://facebook.com/TheHangover just dumps me at a standard FB login screen.

This isn't typical behavior. Usually, you get the page's cover photo and a "You must be logged in to connect with [X] because the page owner restricted this page to [Y]" message.

There may be some kind of bug with the Hangover's page. I've seen odd things like this on some pages I manage before.